# Display data horizontally with two or more select statement

Tags: sql-server

I want to display data horizontally from two or more select statement.
Example:

```
Select DocNo, DocName, Sum(Amount)
From tblCompanyA
Group By DocNo, DocName

Select DocNo, DocName, Sum(Amount)
From tblCompanyB
Group By DocNo, DocName

Select DocNo, DocName, Sum(Amount)
From tblCompanyC
Group By DocNo, DocName
```

If I use Union , the data will display vertically, but I want the data to display as below sample. Tq

```
DocNo   |DocName    |CompanyA Amount    |CompanyB Amount    |CompanyC Amount
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
DN0001   AAA         22345               22312               22311
DN0002   BBB         20000               22321               22456
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you want to `join` the tables instead of using a `union`.

```
Select 
    A.DocNo, A.DocName, 
    Sum(A.Amount) [CompanyA Amount], 
    Sum(B.Amount) [CompanyB Amount], 
    Sum(C.Amount) [CompanyC Amount]
From tblCompanyA A
Join tblCompanyB B on B.DocNo=A.DocNo
Join tblCompanyC C on C.DocNo=A.DocNo
Group By A.DocNo, A.DocName
```

I am assuming all tables have rows for exactly the same set of `DocNo` values, so I used `join`, which means `inner join`.

Comment: Tq. This is the answer! Why can't I think it is really that simple. I'm planning to search for pivot and booom! here just simple join.

Answer (score 0):

You can join those tables together. One of the method is using `LEFT JOIN`

```
select T1.DocNo as DocNo, T1.DocName as DocName, 
       sum(T1.Amount) as 'CompanyA Amount'
       sum(T2.Amount) as 'CompanyB Amount'
       sum(T3.Amount) as 'CompanyC Amount'
from tblCompanyA T1
     left join tblCompanyB T2 on T1.DocNo = T2.DocNo 
     left join tblCompanyC T3 on T1.DocNo = T3.DocNo
Group by T1.DocNo, T1.DocName
```